# Can't hear any other sound while using bluetooth headset during a call (Discord and other social medias) | Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

Problem: Audio/program sounds muted during in-call

Headset: Steel Series Artis 3

Play Youtube music -> Call via Messenger -> The audio disappers

1. Disable Headphones Bluetooth Stereo and leave hands-free audio. It will work but this will affect the sound quality as audio was set to hands-free.
2. At playback, disable headset's hands-free audio. The sound quality is good, works well but this doesn't work during in-call (no sound at all).
3. Disable microphone. Good quality audio. but of course no communications and will definitely need stand-alone microphone.

*Already tried different troubleshooting but no solution at all.

To understand my case:
What I want is to use my Bluetooth headset on playing music and gaming but I needed it also as communication like on Valorant. When you joined a party call, you can hear your teammates but the game sound will be muted. But if you used the hands-free both audio and microphone, it will work but the quality of all the sounds (comms and in-game) has a low quality audio even the music you are playing while gaming will sounds really awful.

Any thoughts on fixing this issue???

*Additional info, I also read on some articles that bluetooth 4.0 and 5.0 dongle does not fix the issue.

Comment: "Any thoughts on fixing this issue???" - This almost sounds like an automatic feature of the software you are using to make the call, to turn down the sound of other applications, so you can hear your call. I would look for settings within Messenger that deal with audio adjustments.

Comment: Windows also has this feature to reduce other audio to 80%, 50% or 0% during a call. Somewhere in control panel, audio.

Comment: Indeed, **it's working as expected**. There are hundreds of thousands of variants of this same question everywhere and the answer is always the same. Now, with newer Bluetooth versions (I believe 5+) with broader bandwidth can enable more channels - HiFi Stereo + mic for HFP - but both devices must support that version and drivers as well, everything must be in perfect alignment. Otherwise those ARE your options: No mic or LowFi  + mic.

Comment: BTW, that's exactly why hardcore gamers DON'T use Bluetooth audio, ever.

Comment: A user submitted an answer, that actually was commentary, but it contained [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu6ti.png) semi-helpful image and suggest you set the option to "do nothing".  They actually asked if you tried to change it, which is a question (and considered a comment), and thus is the reason the answer was deleted.